# TypeError: relu() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Tags: keras, python-3.5, keras-layer, relu

I am getting this error and I don't know why it's coming. Anyone help me out.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore',category=FutureWarning)
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, AtrousConvolution2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Input, Conv2DTranspose, Dense, Flatten
from keras.layers import Dropout, Concatenate, BatchNormalization, Reshape
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.models import Model, model_from_json
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers.convolutional import UpSampling2D
import keras.backend as K
from keras.activations import relu


def g_build_conv(layer_input, filter_size, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='leakyrelu', 
    dropout_rate=g_dropout, norm='inst', dilation=1):
    c = AtrousConvolution2D(filter_size, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=strides,atrous_rate= 
        (dilation,dilation), padding='same')(layer_input)
    if activation == 'leakyrelu':
        c = relu()(c)
    if dropout_rate:
        c = Dropout(dropout_rate)(c)
    if norm == 'inst':
        c = InstanceNormalization()(c)
    return c
```

> Warning (from warnings module):   File
>   "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\layers.py",
>   line 762
>       warnings.warn('The `AtrousConvolution2D` layer ' UserWarning: The `AtrousConvolution2D` layer  has been deprecated. Use instead the
>   `Conv2D` layer with the `dilation_rate` argument. Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "D:\Image Outpaining\outpaint.py", line 146,
>   in 
>       GEN = build_generator()   File "D:\Image Outpaining\outpaint.py", line 120, in build_generator
>       g1 = g_build_conv(g_input, 64, 5, strides=1)   File "D:\Image Outpaining\outpaint.py", line 102, in g_build_conv
>       c = relu()(c) TypeError: relu() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keras.activations.relu` is a function, not a layer, so you are calling it incorrectly. To add the ReLu as a layer, do the following:

```
from keras.layers import Activation

if activation == 'leakyrelu':
    c = Activation("relu")(c)
```